# What is the output of the integrator? How do I find the frequency? Op-amp integrator+Schmitt trigger

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, pwm, schmitt-trigger, integrator

This is the circuit:

[image]

Integrator analysis:

[image]

From this formula I don´t know how to get the frequency. (I don't know if this is right, but I think it is.)

I found a website that says the frequency is R3/4R1xR2xC, but why? Where should I start?

Comment: What is Vx if the op-amp is balanced?

Comment: When the output of the integrator reaches 9V the Schmitt Trigger swtiches to +SAT(12v) and when it goes down to 3V it switches to -SAT(0V).

Comment: https://shinojvk.uccollege.edu.in/wp-content/uploads/sites/196/2016/11/Triangularwave.pdf   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BigOFD-kGmI